# Adding a product attribute to a product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm having these [product attributes](http://bit.ly/1CyFNT6).
I'm trying to add those to a product like this:

```
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, array('15.1', '16.0'), 'pa_empirum-compatibility');
```

or this:

```
update_post_meta($product_id, 'pa_empirum-compatibility', array('15.1', '16.0'));
```

Sadly these approaches don't work. What's the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
*   Set Product Category
*/
wp_set_object_terms($product_id, 'Software Packages', 'product_cat', true);

/*
*   Set Product Attribute Taxonomy with one element
*/
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array('Empirum'), 'pa_platform');
$attribute_platform = Array('pa_platform' => Array(
    'name' => 'pa_platform',
    'value' => '',
    'is_visible' => '1',
    'is_variation' => '1',
    'is_taxonomy' => '1'
));
update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', $attribute_platform);

/*
*   Set Product Attribute Taxonomy with two elements
*/
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, array('15.1', '16.0'), 'pa_empirum-compatibility');
$attribute_empirum = Array('pa_empirum-compatibility' => Array(
    'name' => 'pa_empirum-compatibility',
    'value' => '',
    'is_visible' => '1',
    'is_variation' => '1',
    'is_taxonomy' => '1'
));
update_post_meta($post_id, '_product_attributes', $attribute_empirum);
```